# can't getting updated text of JTextField

Tags: java, swing

i can't getting updated text of JTextField from other class.

change text of JTextField ( from Names ) and go to Main tabbedPane and click button. updated text not appears on JOptionPane.

this is Frame.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Frame {
    
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel pnl;
    JButton btn;
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    Names n;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame x = new Frame();
    }
    
    public Frame() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->Window());
    }

    public void Window() {
        n = new Names();
        frame = new JFrame();
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        pnl = new JPanel();
        btn = new JButton("get Name");
        btn.addActionListener(e->JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n.getName()));
        pnl.add(btn);
        tabbedPane.addTab("main", pnl);
        tabbedPane.addTab("name", new Names());
        frame.add(tabbedPane);
        frame.setBounds(360, 130, 900, 550);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
}
```

this one is Names.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Names extends JPanel {
    
    JTextField tf;
    public Names() {
        tf = new JTextField("test");
        tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));
        this.add(tf);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return tf.getText();
    }
    
}
```

thanks for efforts.

Comment: You can't keep creating a new instance of your Names class. That instance will NOT be visible on the frame. You need to create an instance of the Names class when you create the frame and add the panel to the frame at that time. Then your ActionListener needs to reference that class.

Comment: Thank you , can you please provide an example ?

Comment: You already know how to create your JButton with a variable name add add it to the tab. You do the same with the Names class. You create an instance with a variable name and then add it to the tab. Then in the ActionListener you reference the Names variable and invoke the getName() method. Give it a try and post your updated code if you still have problems.

Comment: I've updated my code, can you please look again ? It is not working still. Thank you so much.

Comment: I specifically stated: *...You create an instance with a variable name and then add it to the tab.* - Why are you using: `tabbedPane.addTab("name", new Names());`? Why are you creating a second instance? You created a button variable and added it to a panel. It is no difference with the Names variable. You create the instance and then add the instance to the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a second and have a look at the following...

```
n = new Names();
//...
btn.addActionListener(e->JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n.getName()));
//...
tabbedPane.addTab("name", new Names());
```

What do you think is going to happen here?

The instance of `Names` which the button is interacting with is NOT the instance of `Names` that the user is interacting with

Change it to...

```
n = new Names();
//...
btn.addActionListener(e->JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n.getName()));
//...
tabbedPane.addTab("name", n);
```

On a side note, this...

```
tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));
```

is a really bad idea and will come back to haunt you.  Instead make use of the `setColumns` method (or constructor) to set the number of displayed characters the text field should attempt to display

Comment: Thank you so much, i am just a mad beginner. now i got my mistake.